# NSURLSession - как использовать данные ответа вне блока

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Друзья, подскажите кто знает - 
Есть метод пользовательского класса, который возвращает переменную NSData - responceData. Она инициализируется ответом от сервера в коде блока.
Проблема в том что мой метод выполняет return и выходит из метода раньше чем входит в блок с респонсом, таким образом возвращая nil.

Какие есть пути решения такой ситуации

```
-(NSData *) getDataFromServer {
    __block NSData *responceData = nil;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration= [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlForResource];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        responceData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:data];
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    return responceData;
}
```

Comment: даже не знаю с какой стороны начинать объяснять. Короче говоря с асинхронным выполнением return не работает, как вы уже сами и сказали - поскольку на момент ретурна ваши данные с сервера еще не пришли. Вам надо в своем completionHandler написать код, который будет отпарвлять вашу responseData куда вам надо

Comment: ок, спасибо. А так, для общего развития - копать в сторону NSThread?? а можно ли как то указать на синхронное выполнение - я так понимаю - пока не выполнится - следующий код не выполняется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поддержу ответ от @Max в комментариях. Рекомендую вам переделать на асинхронное выполнение c `completionBlock`. Примерно так:

```
- (NSData *)getDataFromServer:(void(^)(NSData *))completion {
    //..
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // handle error
        completion(data);
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    //..
}
```

Вот если прям надо выполнить синхронно код, то можно сделать двумя способами.
1) Без использования `NSURLSession`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
```

2) Дождаться выполнения синхронного кода. Например, с помощью `dispatch_group`

```
- (NSData *)getDataFromServer {
    __block NSData *responseData = nil; // модификатор __block, позволяет менять указатель внутри блока кода
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group); // добавляем в группу задачу

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // handle error
        responseData = data;
        dispatch_group_leave(group); // наша задача завершена
    }];

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return responseData;
}
```

Comment: очень интересно. Вариант с     completion

Comment: Вариант с completion  - из своего метода я вызываю блок в который передаю респонс с NSData. Каким образом этот респонс вернуть из метода  getDataFromServer и обойти момент с возвратом nil??

Comment: А вариант с NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] - дейстивтельно класс. Обхожусь без NSURLSession вообще. В этом случаем код выполняется синхронно?? Какие есть подводные камни этого способа(по сравнению с NSURLSession) ???

Comment: Интересно, за счет чего так происходит - 1. Ответ от сервера занимает одинаковое время ка в случае с NSData так и NSURLSession. Но в случае NSData  код не выполняется пока не пришел ответ , а в   NSURLSession - наоборот?

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` блочит текущую нить пока не получим ответ от сервера. Это и есть минус этого метода. Если заблочится главная-нить, айфон не будет реагировать на нажатия. `NSURLSession` по сути делает тоже самое, но без блокировки. Как закончиться загрузка, код из `completion` блока будет вызван. Рекомендую почитать про асинхронное выполнение кода, например, вот тут https://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial