# Потоки. Как заставить метод вернуть значение, получаемое в другом потоке данных

Tags: objective-c, rest, afnetworking, blocks

Суть такова: есть корзина товаров, которая хранится на сервере. По запросу я получаю json в качестве NSArray, в котором элементами являются NSDictionary, каждый из которых, в свою очередь, содержит параметры товара как ID, image, amount и др. Мне нужно обновлять счетчик в боковом меню мобильного приложения (МП) в соответствии с количеством добавленных товаров (сумма параметров amount у всех товаров).
Весь механизм обновления счетчика в МП уже осуществлен, нужно лишь возвращать в методе количество.

```
- (NSInteger)countOfProductsInCart {

__block NSInteger itemsInCart = 0;

[[OCRESTAPIClient sharedClient] fetchCartWithCompletion:^(NSArray *objects) {

    for (NSDictionary *item in objects) {
        itemsInCart += [[item objectForKey:@"amount"] integerValue];
    }
}];

return itemsInCart;

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что вначале проходит код программы, а только потом все действия в блоке. Соответственно return всегда возвращает 0 и только потом уже счетчик обновляется. Как мне вернуть в методе уже посчитанное значение itemsInCart?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578117/nsurlsession-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Спасибо! Понял, как нужно сделать. Даже и не подумал, что можно использовать те же блоки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте найденное решение в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
- (void)countProductsInCart:(void(^)(NSInteger))completion {

[[OCRESTAPIClient sharedClient] fetchCartWithCompletion:^(NSArray *objects) {

    NSInteger itemsInCart = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *item in objects) {
        itemsInCart += [[item objectForKey:@"amount"] integerValue];
    }

    completion(itemsInCart);
}];
}
```